# Read the columns name and getting subscript out of bounds - R

Tags: r

I have a matrix (RR) that the column names are integer. When I refer to the elements of the marix like `RR[x, c("5")]` it works fine but when I put change it to

```
Myindex <-5
RR[x, c("Myindex")]
```

I get the error `subscript out of bounds`. I could not understand it so far.

BTW, 5 is just an example.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: did you try RR[x, Myindex]

Comment: You can refer to a row or column of a matrix by its index, or by its name (if such a name exists). `Myindex <-5` followed by `RR[x, c(Myindex)] ` is the same as `RR[x, c(5)] ` is the same as `RR[x, 5]`. `RR[x, c("Myindex")]` tells R to look for the column named "MYindex".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you name the column names as `numbers` it is taken as `character` column names.

```
rr <- matrix(1:15,3,5)
colnames(rr) <- c(21:25)
rr
#      21 22 23 24 25
# [1,]  1  4  7 10 13
# [2,]  2  5  8 11 14
# [3,]  3  6  9 12 15

rr[1,"23"]
# 23              ## column name is 23
#  7 

my_index <- 4
rr[3,my_index]
# 24              ## column name is 24
# 12 

my_index <- "25"
rr[3,my_index] 
# 25              ## column name is 25
# 15 

colnames(rr) <- as.integer(c(21:25))
rr
#   21 22 23 24 25
# [1,]  1  4  7 10 13
# [2,]  2  5  8 11 14
# [3,]  3  6  9 12 15

class(colnames(rr))
# [1] "character"
```